# How to parse json from http response in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have an API in my localhost. when I call it on browser, I will see this information:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"STATUS":"202","STATUS_DT":"98/12/07","CitizenMobile":"091234567","PROFILEKEY":"1233"}
</string>
```

I want to use this information in my code and `parse` it as `json`. my code is:

```
import json
import requests

url = ""
response = requests.get(url)

print("type of response= ",type(response))
print(response.status_code)

data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)

print(parsed)
```

My output is:

```
type of response=  <class 'requests.models.Response'>
200

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MN/dev/New Project/form/WebService/TEST_MAZAHERI/Test_Stack.py", line 11, in 
 <module>
parsed = json.loads(data)
File "C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\MN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in 
raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I encountered this error : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

just use response.json to get data in json format

```
import json
import requests

url = ""
response = requests.get(url)

print("type of response= ",type(response))
print(response.status_code)

data = response.json # changed here

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works fine.
JSON is in XML, get the data, put that into xml library as `string` and get json from tag.

```
>>> data = r'<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> {"STATUS":"202","STATUS_DT":"98/12/07","CitizenMobile":"091234567","PROFILEKEY":"1233"}</string>'

>>> from io import StringIO
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> root = etree.parse(StringIO(data))
>>> r = root.getroot()
>>> r.tag #also, you can iterate through particular tag, if xml has multiple tags
'{http://tempuri.org/}string'
>>> r.text #Get json text
' {"STATUS":"202","STATUS_DT":"98/12/07","CitizenMobile":"091234567","PROFILEKEY":"1233"}'
>>>

>>> import json
>>> json.loads(r.text)
{'STATUS': '202', 'STATUS_DT': '98/12/07', 'CitizenMobile': '091234567', 'PROFILEKEY': '1233'}
>>> #further operations add here.
```